# redirect uri different for each user in OAuth 2.0 (dynamic redirect uri)?

Tags: api, security, redirect, oauth, oauth-2.0

We have a public API that supports OAuth 2.0 server and client flow. Per OAuth 2.0 spec, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749, each integration application will have 1 application key and users using that application will authorize that application for API access of user's data.

Things worked fine until we find application developers suggesting their users to create one application key each as users will all have their own redirect uri. Put aside the false API usage information it creates, we are seeing a big increase in application key creations that is not tolerated by our API agency.

I am wondering if we can suggest such application developers to add an extra layer for redirect between our oauth server and their users' redirect uri. So their application key will be created with a redirect uri that actually loads a page created by their application, then redirects to the user's specific redirect uri, which is inputted at the user's registration.

Hope I explain it well. I am wondering whether this exposes any more security vulnerabilities than it already has. My point is someone has to do the redirect anyways, rather than we do it with all the unnecessary extra information involved, we'd like to let our client applications take control of it.

Any suggestions/hints/clues/ideas are deeply appreciated.

Comment: Is not clear. 1st Witch flow (grant_type) do you use ? 2nd Each App can have many redirect url you can add here. Is not clear what the developers do and what are the scenario and actors. Can you add a simple scheme of what you doing ?

Comment: thank you for the comment, Max. it is either authorization code (server) or implicit (client) flow of OAuth 2.0. Hmm. what I have heard about wordpress plugin use case is, each user would have their own domain name they would like to redirect to. So multiple preregistered redirects for the application does not help much here